# Is it possible to track time while tracking a polyline using QField

Tags: qfield

I am tracking my footpath using QField. However, it looks like it is not possible to get any automated information as time etc.
Is that correct or is there any way to automatic track some information as times etc.?

Comment: not sure about qfield but there are a lot of apps to create a gpx trace, where you could find times and positions.

Comment: yes sure, but qfields brings some advantages for our workflow when digitalizing in the field. The tracking option is just a addon we would like to use. So if you know some apps for digitalizing in the field which are better than qfieds please let me know and we may try them.

Comment: you could use an automatic timestamp that would track time of creation of a feature or time of last modification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Vector Properties > Attributes Form tab, you can select a field that you'll use for the timestamp. In the *default Value Box*, write this expression:

**now()**

now everytime you'll create a feature, the function will be called and the time of creation will be written in the chosen field.

Comment: Great thanks, that works. Actually when I read your answer I thought that it is not the solution as I am interested in the timestamp at the beginning and not at the end, but in QField it saves the expression before editing. There I get exactly what I want.